# Apache won't serve pages on my Raspberry Pi

Tags: php, apache, configuration, installation, raspberry-pi

I've installed PHP 5.6 on my Raspberry Pi (from the Jessie repo), as well as Apache2. When I access http://192.168.2.50/ (the Pi's IP-address) it's not serving the `index.php` or `index.html` file in `~/var/www/`.

Just an hour ago I was running PHP 5.4 from the Wheezy repo, this was working fine. I've checked if apache was running (using `top`) and I see there are apache2-processes. To be extra sure I've used `service apache2 stop` and then `service apache2 start` to guarantee the webserver is running.

The current output on `http://192.168.2.50` is:

```
Not Found

The requested URL / was not found on this server.

Apache/2.4.10 (Raspbian) Server at 192.168.2.50 Port 80
```

Any suggestions how to get the Pi to serve PHP/webfiles correct again?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was an easy 'fix'. The new PHP's root folder is `~/var/www/html/`. All is working fine. Good luck future solution seekers ;)